# Alternative to java webapp for project for building Facebook

Tags: web-applications, project, jenkins

I was looking for some directions when choosing what way to go in our school project. We have a project course to learn how to operate when using scrum or agile project management. Our objective is to build a version of Facebook, with our own features. (we do not need solutions to assignments).

We have looked into maven and found webapp framework to be a nice alternative. But we have no experience in development in web apps, we have just used terminal based programs and build a lot of algorithms and other stuff in java. We have studied 3 programming courses. We are 10 people with 5 programers and 5 designers.

But when looking into web apps we understand that the are is way bigger than expected, so i browsed the web a couple of hours but its hard to know if it can be an alternative for us and our objective.

We also looking for some nice framework (if we need one?) to handle the graphics and design of the page, we all using eclipse but of course we can adjust.

so we are simply looking for the best option to build a web app when using java code, or alternative that can suite us better.

Right now i have a server with a domain name where i have setup a subversion server, tomcat6 container, jenkins ci, mysql database, ssh. And we can all push and commit and trigger jenkins to build our projects. The only demand from the course is that it have to be web based or client based.

I have looked over the net but when none of us have any experience of JSP/webapp development i find it easier to ask the pros :)

Worth to mention is that we understand we have to learn a ton of new things but that is also the whole point with the course. We have studied database design and a lot of other course so i think we can handle it. Also that the course teachers told us its better to build in php which noone in our team have any direct knowledge about.

Regards
Jonathan